# Best Practice for following multiple authentication backends in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, backend

I am trying to implement an authentication system for 2 different sets of users in Django. A student(using his username & password), A developer (using his email & password). Currently I have a (common) UserProfile model which will be shared by Student, Developer. Here is my models code:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)#this will be used as his unique url identifier
    objects = UserProfileManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(UserProfile):
     ''' some student specific fields might go here '''

class Developer(UserProfile):
    ''' some developer specific fields might go here '''
```

And in settings.py I gave:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'users.UserProfile'
```

I was getting authentication working with just UserProfile model. But as soon as I introduced Student, Developer the whole thing screwed up. I am getting

> UserProfile has no attribute
>   'DoesNotExist'

(this is from the UserProfileManager exists method) and also

> SiteProfileNotAvailable

error. (I am getting these errors even before I started writing email auth backend.). Am I missing anything ? What's the best path to follow to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the abstract definition of UserProfile. Things should work when you leave the 'abstract = True' away. But be aware of how this changes your table scheme.

Comment: If we leave Abstract=True, then it will be creating UserProfile records in Db. Right ? I want to avoid that. I want Student, or Developer profiles to be created in the respective tables. I think the reason why I went for creating two models(Student, Developer) is, if we have only one UserProfile model and differentiating Student/Developer is done by a simple flag, then anyone is forced to use only one auth backend. Right ? Since I wanted multiple auth backends, I resorted multiple types of userprofiles(Student, Developer)